# how to fix "django-admin not recognized"

Tags: python, django, cmd, django-admin

I just formatted my OS due some reason so installed python and django again. I tried to create the python project in the same environment as previous project but unlike that it does not recognizes the "django-admin" command please help me to solve this issue.

I tried reinstall it with pip and also created the environmental variable for django still not worked.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: did you try `python -m django startproject`? If I'm reading the source code right, it should do the same thing.

Comment: Have you installed Django in the virtualenv you are using? If so, add the `django-admin.py` file to your Python path

Comment: @Stevy yes instealled django in virtualenv and will add it python path. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you accept the answer that answered your question by clicking on the checkmark of the answer? This way it shows that the question has been answered and your problem is solved

Comment: okay I will do it. Sorry I am new to this plateform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you installed Django in the virtualenv you are currently using. Also make sure you added the `django-admin.py` file to your Python PATH.

If you want to start your project now and reinstall and fix the PATHs later, you can do:

```
<path_to_django-admin.py> startproject <project_name> 

# An example
C:\Python3.7\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I guess I learned new thing today. I really appreciate you

Comment: still something to ask I had already installed django in my environment in previous OS and was carrying the same file in this than why it was still bothering me.

Comment: I am not really sure but it is probably because it was not in the Python PATH of your new OS

Answer (score 3):

If You installed everything well and good you have pip and Django set, try this one, in your terminal

```
python -m django startproject NameofProject
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it on vs code powershell:
python -m django startproject Project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).